# Java pattern matcher behaviour

Tags: java, regex

say I compile a regex pattern:

```
 String myString = "manifest"; 
 p = Pattern.compile( myPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE  );
 Matcher m = p.matcher( myString );
 if ( m.matches() ){
   .....
 }
```

When I specify `myPattern` as `ni` for example, `myString` doesn't get matched. But when I specify `myPattern` as `.*ni.*` , then it gets matched.

In a later part of my code, I will want to replace whatever is defined in `myPattern` with a new pattern. For example, if I specify `ni` as the 2 characters to replace, then it will only replace `ni`. If i specify `.*ni.*` , then the whole string will be replaced with new pattern. Now my problem is it doesn't get matched.

What could be solution to this?
thanks

Comment: direclty use .replace ?

Comment: How are you *using* `m`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on which `Matcher` method you use:

- matches(): true if, and only if, **the entire region sequence** matches this matcher's pattern
- find(): true if, and only if, **a subsequence of the input sequence** matches this matcher's pattern

Example:

```
String input = "manifest";
Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("ni").matcher(input);
System.out.println(m1.matches()); // false
System.out.println(m1.find()); // true
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile(".*ni.*").matcher(input);
System.out.println(m2.matches()); // true
System.out.println(m2.find()); // false
```

Also, find() allows you to iterate over the matches:

```
while (m2.find()) {
    String groupX = m2.group(x);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) tries to match the **entire** input against the pattern (as it says in the documentation), and of course `manifest` isn't an exact match for `ni` but is an exact match for `.*ni.*`. But if you use [`find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--), for instance, it'll search for the pattern somewhere *within* the input. There's also [`lookingAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt--), which tries to match the pattern at the "current" position within the input.

Comment: hi thanks, i used `matches`. So i should use `find` ...i will give it a try. thanks