# Java Pattern Matcher Woes

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm looking for a pattern to check for boolean terms but only in certain conditions:

- If they exist by them selves
    String a = "AND";
    String b = "\tand";
    String c = "and      ";
- If they are not part of a word or phrase
    String d = "This or that";
- Terms or phrases to ignore:
    String e = "band";
    String f = "L'or"
    String g = "can do";

The code I have so far only find them if they have spaces before and after the delimiter and any sort of adjustment breaks what progress I have. [I used this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926484/java-pattern-matcher-behaviour) as reference but still no dice. I have tried using both find() and matches() but find seems to be too broad in its scope and matches doesn't seem broad enough. Any ideas?

```
final static Pattern booleanTerms = Pattern.compile("(.*)(( OR )|( or )|( NOT )|( not )( AND )|( and ))(.*)");

public static void main(String[] args) {

Set<String> terms = new HashSet<String>();
terms.add(" OR"); //false
terms.add("or "); //false
terms.add("OR"); // false
terms.add(" or "); //true
for (String s : terms) {
    System.out.println(findDilims(s));
} // end for loop

} // end main method

public static boolean findDilims(String s) {
    Matcher matcher = booleanTerms.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
} // end method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you want to find them only if they are by themselves and not as part of a phrase. Then you don't want to start and end your pattern with `(.*)`.

It seems you also want to find them even if there is whitespace around them. Then you would need to start and end your patter with `\s*`. You also want to find them even if there is no space before or after. Then you don't want to have space on your patterns, like for example in `( or )`.

And it seems you want this to be case insensitive so you might want to set that with `(?i)`

```
final static Pattern booleanTerms = Pattern.compile("(?i)(\s*)((or)|(not)|(and))(\s*)");
```

Comment: Ah, thanks SiggiSv. Seems like I over build expressions and don't work my way backwards with improvements. Great tip on the case insensitivity!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting `false` for " OR", "or ", and "OR" is because your pattern is explicitly looking for boolean terms with a space both before or after: e.g. `( OR )` looks for `" OR "`.

Instead of requiring spaces before and after to ensure that each boolean term is a word, you probably want to use word boundaries instead:

```
Pattern.compile("\b(( OR )|( or )|( NOT )|( not )|( AND )|( and ))\b");
```

You can use `\s*` to add optional whitespace to the beginning and end of your regex. That way `" OR   \t "` will also match.

```
Pattern.compile("\s*\b(( OR )|( or )|( NOT )|( not )|( AND )|( and ))\b\s*");
```

`matcher.matches()` should now work fine.

Comment: @Spinish, thanks for the post. Your solution is quite similar to SiggiSv's but I accepted his only because he threw in a piece that shortened the expression...(?i).

Answer (score 0):

You need a character class either end of the terms as an alternation:

```
(?i)(^\s*|[^a-z]\s)(or|not|and)(\s[^a-z]|\s*$)
```

And you only need one line:

```
public static boolean findDilims(String s) {
    return s.matches(".*(?i)(^\\s*|[^a-z]\\s)(or|not|and)(\\s[^a-z]|\\s*$).*");
}
```